# MySQL, PHP - WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I create query as below, but I have a problem with WHERE part:

```
$get_products = "SELECT P.*, C.`category_name`,
                 GROUP_CONCAT(`category_name` SEPARATOR ', ') 
                 AS cat 
                 FROM `products` P 
                 NATURAL JOIN `categories` C 
                 NATURAL JOIN `product_to_categories` 
                 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(`category_id`, '$answers')
                 GROUP BY `product_name` 
                 ORDER BY count(C.`category_id`) DESC";
```

So if I have products i.e.:
[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hXUBNhZ8yF9D6WifeWS2Hb/1)

**APPLE** belonging to the categories: **FRUIT**, **GREEN**, **ROUND**
**WHEEL** belonging to the categories: **MACHINES**, **BLACK**, **ROUND**
**BANANA** belonging to the categories: **FRUIT**, **YELLOW**, **CUBOID**
**PHONE** belonging to the categories: **ELECTRONICS**, **BLACK**, **CUBOID**
**TOMATO** belonging to the categories: **ROUND**, **VEGETABLE**, **RED**
**PIZZA** belonging to the categories: **ROUND**, **COLOURFUL**, **DISH**

and select categories: **ROUND**, **FRUIT**, **GREEN**, **MACHINES**, **VEGETABLE**
thanks to FIND_IN_SET I will receive:

```
    +--------------+---------------------+
    | product_name | cat                 |
    +--------------+---------------------+
    | APPLE        | FRUIT, GREEN, ROUND |
    +--------------+---------------------+
    | TOMATO       | VEGETABLE, ROUND    |
    +--------------+---------------------+
    | WHEEL        | MACHINES, ROUND     |
    +--------------+---------------------+
    | BANANA       | FRUIT               |
    +--------------+---------------------+
    | PIZZA        | ROUND               |
    +--------------+---------------------+
```

Now I am trying to set one of categories mandatory, so it should work like this:

1. I am selecting products with categories **ROUND**, **FRUIT**, **GREEN**, **MACHINES**, **VEGETABLE**.
2. let say that **ROUND** is the main (obligatory) category and I should receive:

   ```
    +--------------+---------------------+
    | product_name | cat                 |
    +--------------+---------------------+
    | APPLE        | FRUIT, GREEN, ROUND |
    +--------------+---------------------+
    | TOMATO       | VEGETABLE, ROUND    |
    +--------------+---------------------+
    | WHEEL        | ROUND, MACHINES.    |
    +--------------+---------------------+
   ```
3. So from all the products belonging to the **ROUND** category, I am also looking for **FRUIT**, **GREEN**, **MACHINES**, **VEGETABLES**.

   I tried this clause:

```sql
    WHERE (category_id IN ('$main_category')
          AND (FIND_IN_SET(category_id, '$answers')));
```

It is almost working. Almost because I am loosing `ORDER BY count` and it returns also **PIZZA** which belongs to **ROUND** but not to any of other categories.

Thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  `product_id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `product_name` VARCHAR(31)
);

INSERT INTO products
  (`product_id`, `product_name`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'APPLE'),
  ('2', 'WHEEL'),
  ('3', 'BANANA'),
  ('4', 'PHONE'),
  ('5', 'TOMATO'),
  ('6', 'PIZZA');

CREATE TABLE categories (
  `category_id` INTEGER,
  `category_name` VARCHAR(31)
);

INSERT INTO categories
  (`category_id`, `category_name`)
VALUES
  ('1', 'FRUIT'),
  ('2', 'GREEN'),
  ('3', 'ROUND'),
  ('4', 'MACHINES'),
  ('5', 'BLACK'),
  ('6', 'YELLOW'),
  ('7', 'CUBOID'),
  ('8', 'ELECTRONICS'),
  ('9', 'DISH'),
  ('10', 'VEGETABLE'),
  ('11', 'RED'),
  ('12', 'COLORFUL');



CREATE TABLE product_to_categories (
  `relation_ID` INTEGER,
  `product_ID` INTEGER,
  `category_ID` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO product_to_categories
  (`relation_ID`, `product_ID`, `category_ID`)
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '1'),
  ('2', '1', '2'),
  ('3', '1', '3'),
  ('4', '2', '4'),
  ('5', '2', '5'),
  ('6', '2', '3'),
  ('7', '3', '1'),
  ('8', '3', '6'),
  ('9', '3', '7'),
  ('10', '4', '5'),
  ('11', '4', '8'),
  ('12', '5', '3'),
  ('13', '5', '10'),
  ('14', '5', '11'),
  ('15', '6', '3'),
  ('16', '6', '9'),
  ('17', '6', '12');
```

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Comment: Hi @Strawberry I described it in points 1,2,3. Thanks!

Comment: So you want the output to look like the table under point 2?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I would like the result to be like the table under point 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g.:

```
SELECT p.*
     , GROUP_CONCAT(COALESCE(c2.category_name,c1.category_name)) name 
  FROM products p 
  JOIN product_to_categories pc1 
    ON pc1.product_id = p.product_id 
  JOIN categories c1 
    ON c1.category_id = pc1.category_id 
  JOIN product_to_categories pc2
    ON pc2.product_id = pc1.product_id
  JOIN categories c2
    ON c2.category_id = pc2.category_id
 WHERE c1.category_name = 'round'
   AND c2.category_name IN ('ROUND','FRUIT', 'GREEN', 'MACHINES', 'VEGETABLE')
 GROUP 
    BY p.product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Looks like it works the way I tried to achieve! thanks!